# Why doesn't GitHub display results for package search in code tab?

Tags: github

I want to search on GitHub: "@angular-architects/ddd" but I got no results on Code tab:

[image]

It is obvious that there are many results, and this is one of them:

https://github.com/mikezks/20220920/blob/main/package.json#L53

Did I use the search wrong, or is it a known bug on GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, per [the search docs](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code#considerations-for-code-search):

> - You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search query: `` . , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ] @ ``. The search will simply ignore these symbols.

The forward slash and at sign are ignored, and there are no hits for `angular-architectsddd`. If you search for the scope and package name *separately* instead, you get some results: https://github.com/search?q=%22angular-architects%22+ddd&type=Code (currently 304 hits)

Note if you're looking for usages of this package in other NPM-based repositories, you can scope the search to package files: https://github.com/search?q=%22angular-architects%22+ddd+filename%3Apackage.json&type=Code
(currently 204 hits)